# store responses of an async method in the same order they are asked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I need to store some google maps coordinates in an array, I obtain the coordinates through the geocoder so I pass the name of the city or the address and it returns me the coordinates.

I found that geocoder must be an async function, because is not giving me the answers in the same order I ask them. So the coordinates are stored in a diferent order that I need.

For example, if I ask for barcelona -> paris -> barcelona the answer is always the coordinates of barcelona -> barcelona -> paris or paris -> barcelona -> barcelona. or if I ask paris -> roma -> oslo it answers in another order.

```
var address = ['Barcelona', 'Viena','Oslo'];
for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++ ) {
   geocoder.geocode({
       'address': address[i]
   }, function (results, status) {

       if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           lineCoordinates.push(results[0].geometry.location);
           cities.push(results[0].address_components[0].long_name);
           console.log("he terminado para:" + results[0].address_components[0].long_name);
       }
   });
}
```

how can I do to store the responses in the correct order?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with callbacks for your purpose. Make your geocoding request to a function like:

```
doGeocode: function (address, postal_code, callback) {
console.log("TEST: " + address.toString());
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address,
    'componentRestrictions': {
        'postalCode': postal_code,
        'country': 'de'
    }
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results);
        callback(results);
    } else {
        //Error handling
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Now you could work within each callback like:

```
doGeocode (adress, postal_code, function (response1){
//Barcelona
  doGeocode (adress, postal_code, function (response2){
  //Viena

   doGeocode (adress, postal_code, function (response3){
      //Oslo


      //here you have all your requested information from all 3 requests
     )};
  )}; 
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have arrays for each of address, lineCoordinates and cities.  I'd scrap that, have just 1 array that contains everything, so you can tie up the city you're making the request for, with its coordinates and name.

```
var cities = [
    {
        name: 'Barcelona',
        longName: '',
        coordinates: ''
    },
    {
        name: 'Viena',
        longName: '',
        coordinates: ''
    },  
    {
        name: 'Oslo',
        longName: '',
        coordinates: ''
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++ ) {
   geocoder.geocode({
       'address': cities[i].name
   }, function (results, status) {
       if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           cities[i].coordinates = results[0].geometry.location;
           cities[i].longName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
       }
   });
}
```